# C# Error "Method Name Excepted" What am i doing wrong

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise4
{
    class MainClass
    {
        private char c;

        public MainClass(char c)
        {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new MainClass('A'), run)); //Error Method Name Excepted : Error Code CS0149
            Thread thB = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new MainClass('B'), run)); //Error Method Name Excepted : Error code CS0149

            thA.Start();
            thB.Start();

            thA.Join();
            thB.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to C# and i really don't understand what is wrong there.

**More precisely the error is here:**

```
new ThreadStart(new MainClass('A') , run )
new ThreadStart(new MainClass('B') , run )
```

This code must creates 5 threads, each of these threads displays a letter 'A' for the first one, 'B' for the second, and so on. 
I tryied to modify the program so that each thread displays its letter in an infinite loop.

Hope i can get some help there!

Comment: I suggest you have a read of http://www.albahari.com/threading/ as this will give you a firm understanding of threading. This will enable you to complete your homework assignment.

Comment: ThreadStart constructr takes a method as its first paramter, not a character. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstart?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @sagi "public void run()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your objects first, and then you can pass the `run` method of those objects to `ThreadStart`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mainA = new MainClass('A');
    var mainB = new MainClass('B');
    Thread thA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mainA.run));
    Thread thB = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mainB.run));
    ...
```

**POST EDITED: An Additional Option**

If you only needed the two initialized objects for this one purpose, you could make this slightly more elegant by handling the initialization in the same lines without declaring and setting the additional variables:

```
    Thread thA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new MainClass('A').run));
    Thread thB = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new MainClass('B').run));
```

Comment: Oh okay so that was my `new MainClass('B') , run` which was wrong thanks =)

Comment: Yes, you were super-close, save for one mispunctuation, in hindsight!

Answer (score 0):

it wont let you call your method `run`  if it is a method u should call `run()` but change the name first. also

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

since your using a value and not an actual `boolean` this says its always true, and the while makes it loop, this will StackOverflow. change the `while` to `if` to just print it once

Comment: I understand but i want to create an infinite loop thats why i use while.

Comment: yes but once that consoles label is set to `A` you arent changing it are you? so recalculating this is a huge waste, and it will flood your console with line after line until it crashes. the program litterally wont be able to do anything else and it will lock. thats one of the reasons to use threads to begin with. good luck though. i learned the hard way too. :)

Comment: you can keep the while loop and use it for logic updates, but i would move the print line out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the way you try to instantiate the **MainClass** object and execute the **run** function that is not correct inside the new Thread.

You can make your code work by modifing "***public static void Main***" as follow :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainClass A = new MainClass('A');
            Thread thA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(A.run));


            MainClass B = new MainClass('B');
            Thread thB = new Thread(new ThreadStart(B.run));

            thA.Start();
            thB.Start();

            thA.Join();
            thB.Join();

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```